# If I use a ribbon cable with my PiTFT, is there a maximum length?

Tags: gpio, pitft

If I wish to detach my PiTFT screen from my Raspberry Pi (Model B) using a ribbon cable, is there a maximum length of cable I can use to prevent latency issues with the screen?

I saw in the PiTFT tutorial it says you may need to set the display to 16khz if using a ribbon cable.

Answer (score -1):

The data can travel as far as 18 inches, but the cable itself can be longer.

[source](https://superuser.com/a/326315)

I can't find anything that disagrees with this, so if you find anything against this please share.

Comment: The reference is to an IDE cable used for IDE disk drives.  It is not relevant to a different type of cable used for a different purpose.

Comment: The difference would only matter if the wire gauge, wire type (copper, stranded, etc), and insulation was different.

Comment: Are you sure there are no other differences which need to be taken into account?  I'm fairly sure the signals being propagated are relevant.  I'm fairly sure telephone wires can be more than 18 inches long.

Comment: Yes, because telephone wires are thicker and different insulation than ribbon and ide cables. The difference between the ide and ribbon is count of cable, and ending (for the most part).

Comment: There are a lot of factors affecting the maximum length of signal cables (vs. power cables, which have other factors) -- frequency of the signals, voltages, capacitance of the cables, etc.    Spend some time browsing electronics.stackexchange.com to get an idea of deep the subject can be.